# Going around the fact that ORM Class already extends DB Class and you need it to extend from Abstract class

Tags: php, oop, orm

My problem has to do with PHP, but it could potentially relate to any other language with an object relational mapper.

Say I have a class Event that extends DbObject and Exception that extends DbObject but I want them both to extend from Abstract Class TimePeriod.  Both objects being ORM objects.

Why?  Because I don't want to manually code getStartTimeStamp() on each type of class that has a start and end date.

Right now I am using interfaces but I feel like it really hurts the DRY of it.

Do I simply redesign it such that Abstract Class TimePeriod extends Dbobject and implement each object extend from it?  Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Why would an exception class extend a dbobject class?

Comment: B/c its ORM object that was generated and it can run queries.

Comment: Which ORM? What would `getStartTimeStamp()` do?

Answer (score 1):

The general solution to the multi-inheritance problem you are facing is aggregation/composition.

It also makes your design clearer. Exception can't be a time period after all.

So what you want is to create a TimePeriod class and pass objects of that class to Exception and Event.
Then you can either call getStartTimeStamp() on the time period object directly like that:

```
$event->getTimePeriod()->getStartTimeStamp();
```

Or create wrapping methods and calling them instead.